# Существует ли в природе рабочий компрессор php кода?

Tags: php

Нечто вроде CSS компрессора - уменьшает размер кода. Дело в том, что приходится работать с чужим кодом, а там черт пойми что, без пол литра не разобраться, вообщем трудно ориентироваться. В интернетах искал, но нужный образец не нашел...

Comment: Как компрессор может помочь разобраться в чужом коде? Ах да и для чего он нужен? Килобайты(!) экономить на сервере? Прошу вас, помните: PHP не отдается клиенту в чистом виде -- отдается результат работы вашего скрипта и тут больше ценна скорость его работы а не вес на сервере!

Comment: поддержу предыдущего оратора. неужели вам в коде jqury.min.js проще разобраться чем в коде  jquery.js ?

Comment: Ну я же не имел ввиду сжимать до jqury.min.js =). Есть CSS компрессор в котором как раз можно выбрать степень сжатия. Можно же код сжать таким образом, чтобы удалились лишние пробелы, знаки табуляции, пустые строки, слегка отформатировались управляющие конструкции... я это имел ввиду.

Comment: Хы... забыл что мне нужно, в итоге из-за этого искал совсем не то, нашел что надо.

Comment: >а там черт пойми что, без пол литра не разобраться

заканчивайте вы это - программирование с помощью пол литра. Очень уж скользкий путь к мастерству, знаете ли. Лучше юзайте печеньки

Comment: так может автору вопроса нужен не компрессор, а форматировщик кода + средства рефакторинга?

Comment: @KoVadim тогда нужно пересесть с блокнота на IDE

Comment: Тогда порекомендуем человеку AStyle для начала (правда в консоли линукса в основном).

Или сайты вида [1](http://phpcodecleaner.com/) или [2](http://phpbeautifier.com/). (просто нашел в гугле первые адекватные).

Хотя некоторые люди пишут такое... что даже с нормальной IDE там не разобраться.

Comment: https://phpcompressor.genasyst.ru/ Это первая версия, пока не развивается.

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял, то код необходимо привести к нормальному виду. Для этого есть сервисы, вроде этого http://beta.phpformatter.com/ либо использовать IDE(Пример, PHPStorm: Code -> Reformat Code... Ctrl+Alt+L).